# message channel name returning an undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm trying to get the channel name of a channel I've created. however, I'm getting `undefined` as if the channel I created does not exist, which it does.

Here is my code:

```js
const new_channel = message.guild.channels.create("New Name").then((channel) => {
  channel.setParent(categoryId)
  channel.setTopic(topic)
})

message.channel.send(`Ticket created in ${new_channel}`);
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If `.create()` returns a `then`able object (which most likely is a `Promise`) then `new_channel` won't be `undefined`.

Comment: `GuildChannelManager.create()` does return a `Promise<GuildChannel>`, as seen in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new_channel` is NOT the `GuildChannel` you just created. It is a `Promise<GuildChannel>`. In other words, it is "promising" that it can deliver you a text channel, and will deliver it to you once the channel has been created via `.then`.

Basically, creating a text channel in Discord takes some time. Discord.js has to send a request to the Discord API, wait for Discord to create the channel, and then get the Discord API's response. Only *then* will Discord.js give you the data for the text channel you created. Hence why we use `.then()`; once the channel has been created, only *then* will the code inside `.then()` be executed.

As for why `new_channel` is undefined, it may be because you are not returning a value in your `.then()`. Therefore, there is nothing further to promise.

So the solution to your problem is to reference the *actual* variable that contains the created channel; the `channel` parameter passed into your `.then()`. Here is an example:

```js
const new_channel = message.guild.channels.create("New Name").then((channel) => {
  channel.setParent(categoryId);
  channel.setTopic(topic);

  message.channel.send(`Ticket created in ${channel.name}`);
})
```

As you can see, your code was already setting the parent and topic of `channel`, not `new_channel`. So it logically makes sense that the name of the channel is also in `channel`, not `new_channel`.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to reference the channel ID of the channel created instead of the object when sending a message. See the example below.

Example:

```js
let guild = await client.guilds.fetch(message.guild.id);
let newChannel = await guild.channels.create("name");
newChannel.setParent("catagory-id");
newChannel.setTopic("The topic of the channel");

message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> Your ticket was created in <#!${newChannel.id}>`);
```

Full Example:

```js
let Discord = require('discord.js');
let client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('messageCreate', async function(message) {
    // Do something

    let guild = await client.guilds.fetch(message.guild.id);
    let newChannel = await guild.channels.create("name");
    newChannel.setParent("catagory-id");
    newChannel.setTopic("The topic of the channel");

    message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> Your ticket was created in <#!${newChannel.id}>`);
});

client.login('your-token');
```